# Cannot resolve symbol 'Auth' google sign-in integration

Tags: android, android-studio

There is another question like this but it's not the same error. I believe I got my dependencies all set up correctly but I keep getting the error that 'Auth' cannot be resolved.

Build Gradle App

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jophyjohnson.budgetme"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.connectsdk:connect-sdk-android:1.6.0'


}
```

Build Gradle Project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Sign-in Activity

```
package com.example.jophyjohnson.budgetme;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

/**
 * Created by Jophy Johnson on 1/23/2016.
 */
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, (GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
```

to your gradle file.

Do note you may need to change `8.3.0` to another version of the play services dependent upon your use case. Such as `7.5.0`, `9.6.1` or `10.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'`
to the dependencies block in the app-level gradle.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.